# calling apex class from lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

lwc: component which should create parking slots under that building based on type of vehicle. In my case when I select two wheeler and create slots it is automatically creating 4 wheeler slots also, but when I select 4 wheeler and created slots it is not creating any.
Please anyone help me I'm beginner to lwc.

lwc js:

```js
import { LightningElement,wire,api,track } from 'lwc'; 
import methodFor2W from '@salesforce/apex/createParkingSlots.methodFor2W';
import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi"; 
import {ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent'; 
import {getObjectInfo} from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi'; 
import {getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import PARKINGSLOT__OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Parking_Slot__c';
import TYPEOFVEHICLE_FIELD from'@salesforce/schema/Parking_Slot__c.Type_of_vehicle__c';
    
export default class Parkingslotscreation extends LightningElement
{
    @api recordId
    @track type1;
    @track value11;
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: PARKINGSLOT__OBJECT })
    objectInfo;
    
    
    @wire(getPicklistValues,{ recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId", fieldApiName: TYPEOFVEHICLE_FIELD })
    typeofvehiclePicklist;
        
    handleChange(event) {
        this.value11 = event.detail.value;
        if(event.target.name =='Typeofvehicle'){
            this.type1 =event.target.value;
        }       
    }
        

    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId'})
    building;

    numberNew;
    handleChange1(event){
        if(event.target.name =='IntValueNew'){
            this.numberNew = parseInt(event.target.value); 
        }
    }
   
    
    handleCreateSlots(){
        methodFor2W({ value2W: this.numberNew , reco2W: this.recordId, type: this.type1 })
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: this.value11+ ' Slots are Created Successfuly',
            message: this.numberNew+ 'slots created for '+this.value11,
            variant: 'success',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
   
}
```

lwc html:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Create 2 Wheeler slots 11 " icon-name="action:new_note" >

        <template if:true={typeofvehiclePicklist.data}>
            <div class="slds">
                <lightning-combobox
                    name="Typeofvehicle"
                    label="Type of vehicle"
                    value={value11}
                    options={typeofvehiclePicklist.data.values}
                    onchange={handleChange}>
                </lightning-combobox>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-m-horizontal_medium">
                <lightning-input type="Integer" label="No of Slots" name="IntValueNew" onchange={handleChange1}></lightning-input>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Create Slots" title="Primary action" onclick={handleCreateSlots} class="slds-align_absolute-center" ></lightning-button>
            </div>

        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Apex controller:

```java
public with sharing class createParkingSlots {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Parking_Slot__c> methodFor2W(Integer value2W, string reco2W, string type ) {
    
        list<Parking_Slot__c> pList = new list<Parking_Slot__c>();
        list<Building__c> b1 = [select id, Name from Building__c where Id=: reco2W];
        for(Building__c b2 :b1){
            for(Integer i=1; i<=value2W; i++){
                Parking_Slot__c ps1 = new Parking_Slot__c();
                ps1.Building__c = b2.Id;
                if(type == '2-Wheeler'){
                    ps1.Type_of_Vehicle__c = '2-Wheeler';
                    pList.add(ps1);
                }
                else if (type == '4-Wheeler'){
                    ps1.Type_of_Vehicle__c = '4-Wheeler';
                    pList.add(ps1);
                }
            }
        }
        insert pList;
        system.debug('Parking Slots Insert for 2W');

        return pList;  
    }

}
```

Comment: Add a catch to methodFor2W to see if the method throws any exception. Additionally add few breakpoints to see the flow of your code & see what values are being passed to controller.